# Nifi putDatabaseRecord error: no value for PrimaryKey?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a putDatabaseRecord Processor that receives a JSON array with field names and values.

Update and insert fail, I can't understand the reason why.
The FlowFile in the Provenance Event looks like:

```
[ {"ID" : 1,"code":1}]
```

Update fails with

```
Record does not have a value for the PrimaryKey column 'ID'
```

Which is false because I can see the column and the value in the JSON FlowFile.

Insert fails with:

```
Record does not have a value for the Required column 'code'
```

but again, it's false!

I don't know which other useful information could I put here...
Maybe the processor configuration:

[image: Processor configuration]
I'd like some help troubleshooting this, any idea welcome.

It's my first attempt at using Nifi.

Comment: What are your settings for the JsonPathReader? Should be an Avro schema with ID and code?

Comment: @mattyb oh gosh, I didn't even know that point, I just copied and example and definition of course doesn't much with my table...I'll try to fix it, let's see.

Comment: now the Processor results in success, but I don't see any update to db...

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, I had **Update Keys** value as **[ID]** instead of just **ID**